# Как SomeInstance.ToString() всегда возвращает правильное название класса?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Собственно вопрос: как и почему автоматически перегружается виртуальный метод базового класса `System.Object` `ToString()`, если мы его явно ни как не трогаем?

В данной технике используется АОП?

Пример кода:

```
using System;

class A
{
    class B
    {
        public void D()
        {
             Console.WriteLine(base.ToString());
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не АОП (аспектно-ориентированное программирование), это ООП (объектно-ориентированное программирование).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего посмотреть имплементацию через Рефлектор или ILSpy. Или на [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab).

```
class object
{
    // ...
    public virtual string ToString()
    {
        return this.GetType().ToString();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Компилятор мог бы применить свою компиляторную магию, но тут она не понадобилась. Метод `GetType()` возвращает настоящий, runtime-тип объекта, а уж тип знает, как он называется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, это я тоже видел, но как можно посмотреть реализацию метода GetType?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Ну, это же рантайм-тип объекта, он прикрепляется к объекту во время его создания. Это уже внутренняя подробность реализации рантайма.

Comment: да это и хотелось бы узнать: как на более низком уровне всё работает.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Думаю, вам лучше Джеффри Рихтера (CLR via C#) никто не расскажет. (Вроде бы английский перевод лучше.)

Comment: Вы наверно будете смеяться, но этот вопрос как раз и возник при чтении этой книги.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Хм. Если даже Джеффри Рихтер не помог, то вам наверное в исходники. Например, [сюда](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp) (строка 242).

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это то что нужно. Буду разбираться.